# Слова, называющие лиц по должности

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как правильно:

1) заведующая садиком Петрова или заведующий садиком Петрова; 
2) Петрова, заведующая (или заведующий) садиком, доложила о ходе ремонтных работ.

В каком случае *заведующий*, а в каком *заведующая*?

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В обоих случаях правильно -- ***заведующая.***

Answer (score 1):

Даже если в штатном расписании значится "заведующий", употребление здесь естественного (при упоминании женщины) слова "заведующая" этой формальности не противоречит: это слово можно трактовать как "постоянно исполняющая обязанности заведующего". И только если в строгом юридическом документе нужно точно назвать где-то прописанную должность "заведующий", уместно употребить мужской род - но в формулировке, не требующей согласования по роду с фамилией. Например, после упоминания должности фамилию можно привести в скобках (для справки, о ком речь) - тогда язык не пострадает.

Answer (score 0):

Логично. Заведующая. Она же женщина.

Answer (score 0):

Т.е правило неправильное????

•   Слова, не имеющие парных образований: педагог, судья, адвокат, менеджер, доцент, профессор, кандидат наук, лауреат конкурса, специалист, консультант, юрист, заведующий отделом, директор и др. В официальной речи существительные этой группы сохраняют форму мужского рода и в тех случаях, когда относятся к лицам женского пола. Например: «педагог Петрова Н.Н. предложила...», «профессор Михайлова Р.О. опубликовала монографию...», «Анисимова В.А. принята на должность заведующего отделом конфиденциального делопроизводства» и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

> Т.е правило неправильное????
>
> • Слова, не имеющие парных образований: педагог, судья, адвокат, менеджер, доцент, профессор, кандидат наук, лауреат конкурса, специалист, консультант, юрист, заведующий отделом, директор и др. В официальной речи существительные этой группы сохраняют форму мужского рода и в тех случаях, когда относятся к лицам женского пола. Например: «педагог Петрова Н.Н. предложила...», «профессор Михайлова Р.О. опубликовала монографию...», «Анисимова В.А. принята на должность заведующего отделом конфиденциального делопроизводства» и т.п.

Правило правильное. Но вы не приняли во внимание ключевое ждесь "слова, ***не имеющие парных образований:***". А "заведующий" как раз имеет. Поэтому здесь вполне уместно именно "заведующая", а вот "заведующий", хотя и допустимо, но вне особо официальной обстановки вызывает некоторый дискомфорт.

Comment: Заведующий отделом и заведующий разные должности??? В правиле выше написано, что "заведующий отделом" - это слово, не имеющее парных образований